# How to run MongoDB using PM2

Tags: mongodb, server, vps, pm2

How do I run MongoDB using PM2? I'm using a Linux VPS (CentOS) and I tried doing this:

```
pm2 mongod
```

^ and that works but the problem is I need to bind IP and DBPath name

```
pm2 mongod -dbpath /home/[ommitted]/data/db --bind_ip [ommitted] -auth
```

^ But that doesn't work because of PM2 flags. So how can I run it using PM2 or at least make it so it doesn't shut down when I close the terminal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create an SH file that runs the command, then run the SH file.

```
1. For example, name it "run.sh"
2. Open/edit file
3. Add this to the first line of the file mongod -dbpath /home/[ommitted]/data/db --bind_ip [ommitted] -auth
4. pm2 start run.sh
```

Another way that you can do is this;

```
pm2 start "mongod -dbpath /home/[ommitted]/data/db --bind_ip [ommitted] -auth"
```

Comment: In case you're tempted to try it, DO NOT do that : pm2 start "systemctl start mongod.service"

Answer (score 0):

The official way would be 
`pm2 start mongod -- -dbpath /home/[ommitted]/data/db --bind_ip [ommitted] -auth`

As shown on their homepage
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

[image]

[image]