# How to start mongdb

Tags: database, mongodb, server, process, pm2

How to start mongodb with pm2 on command line or with bash file.
I am trying this on cmd.

`pm2 start "mongod --dbpath data"`

Comment: Can you share what error you are getting?

Comment: Seems like this is the answer to your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303828/how-to-run-mongodb-using-pm2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run MongoDB using PM2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303828/how-to-run-mongodb-using-pm2)

Comment: i also trien what you are recomending like                                                   
 C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0>pm2 start "mongod -dbpath C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\[ommitted]\data --bind_ip [ommitted] -auth"
[PM2][ERROR] Script not found: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\mongod -dbpath C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\[ommitted]\data --bind_ip [ommitted] -auth